# What it's the event to catch reopen window in iOS?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I need refresh data to controller when user back to windows in Android I'm used the activity.onResume but in iOS I dont know how is the best practices to implemented this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make use of the "focus" event for the window. Something like:

```
win.addEventListener('focus',function(){
  //do something on focus
});
```